# Object on 2D plane ARCore android

Tags: android, android-activity, arcore

I am working on an app where I need to use ARCore. Since I don't have any prior experience in ARCore. I don't know how to do it.

**REQUIREMENT**

I have a requirement where I have to open a camera and place an ARObject on any x,y coordinates.
I know the ARObject needs 'z' as well.
If My camera view shows a shelf with items placed on it, I want to show an ARObject at 3rd item from left. I already have the x,y points of that item on shelf and now just have to place the AR object.
Please let me know if it is even possible or not?

**What I Tried**

- The anchor object. It is not created using x and y coordinates.
- I tried the [Hello Sceneform](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) example from google. But to use that
  I need to calibrate the ARScene first by moving the camera in a
  specific manner.
- I tried the [Augmented Images example](https://proandroiddev.com/augmented-images-with-arcore-and-sceneform-4c3fe774b5bd) from Medium, which lets me add an ARObject/AugmentedImage on the camera without calibrating. But it needs an Augmented Image position as a reference. The item on shelf won't be an AugmentedImage.
- Also, the camera view very blur on the ARScene.

Please guide me how can I achieve this. Any tutorial links are welcome

Comment: I am not sure if i understood your requirements correctly so you have an actual shelf with books and stuff in it right not a virtual shelf? If shelf is real and lets say you have a book in the shelf facing its cover to your camera, you can use that cover as an augmented image if it has enough feature points. Then you can assign positions correctly. And also how do you know x, y coordinates of the items did you measure them with a tape measure?

Comment: @alikanat We are capturing a picture and getting the position of say the book using ocr by calling an API.
Suppose, I don't have books but barcodes, how can I get it's augmented image? is it a simple jpeg? I really don't understand.

Comment: ARCore has Augmented Image Database. So you can create this database using images, simple jpeg is fine. You can use Qr codes or bar codes as well i guess but they have to get a score higher than 75. In Android you can use [arcoreimg tool](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/arcoreimg) for creating databases. Once you have your database you can track the position of these images in your application.

Comment: @alikanat thanks, it worked.
Do you have any idea, how can I get the detected object's image from whole camera view.
Since it matches the image with our AugmentedImageDB, it must be detecting the 'bookcover' in whole camera view. Can we get that book cover only?
The `acquireCameraImage` returns null or whole camera view. How do I get the book view?

Comment: Oh boy that is rough. Only thing i can think of is maybe a solution like this: Calculate positions of the corners of image using  `image.getCenterPose`, `getExtentX` and `getExtentZ`. Then you calculate the distance of device to shelf and find a fov plane area. Then you can find corrensponding pixels of the image i believe but it does not work at every pose of  the device.

Comment: ohh. okay.
One last thing. How can I place my AR rendering object flat on the surface? like laying on plane? I have a ViewRenderer object. which is a custom xml, but I am able to see it's top view only.